# Laravel : Controller not found

Tags: laravel

Help me to create a new folder and route for the `add-post` for my app.Just added new folder on routes and create a file `require_once("Api/post.php");` when i hit `http://localhost:8000/api/addpost` it returns `Class 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\Front\\Controller' not found`. `routes/api.php` look like

```
<?php
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Router;

/** @var Router $api */
$api = app(Router::class);
$api->version('v1', function (Router $api) {
    $api->group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function(Router $api) {
        $api->post('signup', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\Auth\\SignUpController@signUp');
        $api->post('login', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\Auth\\LoginController@login');
        $api->post('logout', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\Auth\\LogoutController@logout');
 });

require_once("Api/post.php"); // Added in routes/Api folder
```

and my `routes/Api/post.php` routes

```
$api->post('addpost', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\Front\\PostController@store');
```

Whats am doing wrong.I didn't get it.

Comment: Let's start from this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing - did u read?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski checking

Comment: @AdamKozlowski see updated

Answer (score 0):

Each route that you define in Routes/api.php accessible by using api prefix like this:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

you can access to this by this url

```
localhost:8000/api/user
```

and also have a review on this 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Comment: when i separate the folder it returns controller not found